# Manifest merger failed : android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.provider.GitHubLoginActivity>

Tags: android

I have upgraded to sdk 33 then this popus up

Manifest merger failed : android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.provider.GitHubLoginActivity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

i have checked my manifist here

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">



 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="com.logista.otbokhly_Driver.activities.DriversActivity"
            android:label="@string/drivers_list"
            android:exported="true" tools:node="merge" />
        <activity android:name="com.logista.otbokhly_Driver.activities.UserChatActivity"  android:exported="true" tools:node="merge"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.logista.otbokhly_Driver.activities.OrderBillActivity"
            android:label="@string/order_bill"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"  android:exported="true" tools:node="merge"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.logista.otbokhly_Driver.activities.DriverDetailsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"  android:exported="true" tools:node="merge"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.logista.otbokhly_Driver.activities.DriverBalanceActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"  android:exported="true" tools:node="merge" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.logista.otbokhly_Driver.activities.NotificationActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_notification"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"  android:exported="true" tools:node="merge"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.logista.otbokhly_Driver.activities.ProfileActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"  android:exported="true" tools:node="merge"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.logista.otbokhly_Driver.activities.SignUpActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"  android:exported="true" tools:node="merge"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.logista.otbokhly_Driver.activities.LogInActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"  android:exported="true" tools:node="merge"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.logista.otbokhly_Driver.activities.SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:exported="true" tools:node="merge">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" android:exported="true"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" android:exported="true"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.logista.otbokhly_Driver.activities.ChatActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"  android:exported="true" tools:node="merge"/>
        <activity android:name="com.logista.otbokhly_Driver.activities.SendFormActivity" android:exported="true"  tools:node="merge"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.logista.otbokhly_Driver.activities.ContactUsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_contact_us"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"  android:exported="true" tools:node="merge"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.logista.otbokhly_Driver.activities.HomeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"  android:exported="true" tools:node="merge"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.logista.otbokhly_Driver.invice_for_user"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"  android:exported="true" tools:node="merge"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.logista.otbokhly_Driver.document_page"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"  android:exported="true" tools:node="merge"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.logista.otbokhly_Driver.notification_act"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"  android:exported="true" tools:node="merge"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.logista.otbokhly_Driver.invoice"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"  android:exported="true" tools:node="merge"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.logista.otbokhly_Driver.edit_profile"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"  android:exported="true" tools:node="merge"/>

        <activity android:name="com.logista.otbokhly_Driver.weiting_order"  android:exported="true" tools:node="merge"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.logista.otbokhly_Driver.homeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"  android:exported="true" />
        <activity android:name="com.logista.otbokhly_Driver.registration"  android:exported="true" tools:node="merge"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.logista.otbokhly_Driver.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"  android:exported="true" tools:node="merge"/>

        <service
            android:name="com.logista.otbokhly_Driver.services.LocationService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" tools:node="merge"/>

        <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" android:exported="true"/>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
        tools:ignore="ManifestOrder" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<!--    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />-->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

</manifest>
```

and gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } //<<--Insert this above google()
        maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
       // classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14' // or latest version

        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } //<<--Insert this above google()
        maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
        google()
        jcenter()

    }

    subprojects {
        project.configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                        && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                    details.useVersion "27.1.1"
                }
                if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.core'
                        && !details.requested.name.contains('androidx') ) {
                    details.useVersion "1.0.1"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Nothing is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade your Firebase related dependencies, as your app targets latest version of android, the dependencies have to be compatible and if that didn't work then downgrade the SDK version.